# PHP - why is this date function not erroring out

Tags: php, date, format, utc

```
function convertDT($TS) {
    $TS = strtotime($TS);
    $TS -= date("Z");
    $newTS = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $TS);
    return $newTS;
}

echo "Good: ".convertDT('2010-04-20 01:23:45')."\n";
echo "Bad: ".convertDT('2010-31-20 01:23:45')."\n";
```

The second date returns: 1969-12-31T23:00:00Z

Why? Should this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime()` returns `false` when you give it an invalid timestamp.  `false` is equivalent to `0` if you use it in an integer context, so when you pass it to this line:

```
$newTS = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $TS);
```

You are effectively creating a date from a timestamp of `0`.  In terms of the UNIX epoch, `0` is January 1st, 1970, which is where you're getting your end result from.

Your best bet would be soemthing like this:

```
$TS = strtotime($TS);
if($TS === false) {
    throw new Exception("Invalid timestamp.");
}
//etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

On your second date, you are trying to create a date of month 31 and of day 20. Even if you reversed these, it wouldn't make sense. Probably a typo.

Comment: yes, I want to validate and throw an error instead of returning the 1969 date

Comment: @Phill: `strtotime` is erroring out because you're giving it a bogus date. You can check to see if it returns FALSE on error. In the second line of your example, you're basically doing `0 - date('Z')` everytime, because FALSE is getting casted to 0.

Answer (score 0):

read this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

> **Errors/Exceptions**
>
> Every call to a date/time function
>   will generate a E_NOTICE if the time
>   zone is not valid, and/or a E_STRICT
>   or E_WARNING message if using the
>   system settings or the TZ environment
>   variable. See also
>   date_default_timezone_set()

This function will not generate any error even if input string is not valid.